# Running docker with mysql and django backend

Tags: python, mysql, django, docker

My first time dealing with docker and i kinda can't start it up properly.
This is my docker-compose.yml file:

```
version: "3"
services:
  mysql:
    image: mysql
    container_name: my-mysql
    restart: on-failure
    ports:
      - 3306:3306
    volumes:
      - ./mysql_data:/var/lib/mysql
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: ""
      MYSQL_USER: intranet
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: ""
      MYSQL_DATABASE: intranet
      MYSQL_ALLOW_EMPTY_PASSWORD: yes
    healthcheck:
      test:
        [
          "CMD",
          "mysqladmin",
          "ping",
          "-h",
          "localhost",
          "-u",
          "root",
          "-pmy-root-password",
        ]
      interval: 10s
      timeout: 5s
      retries: 5

  backend:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    container_name: my-backend
    restart: on-failure
    volumes:
      - .:/app
    environment:
      DATABASE_URL: mysql2://intranet@mysql:3306/intranet
      SECRET_KEY: x
    ports:
      - 8000:8000
    depends_on:
      - mysql
    command: ["./etc/entry", "web-prod"]
```

I created in MySQL workbench database 127.0.0.1:3306 with name intranet and code in it:

```
CREATE USER 'intranet'@'localhost';
CREATE DATABASE intranet;
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON intranet.* TO 'intranet'@'localhost';
FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
```

And I got dockerfile like this:

```
FROM python:3.7

RUN wget https://dl.google.com/cloudsql/cloud_sql_proxy.linux.amd64 -O /usr/local/bin/cloud_sql_proxy \
    && chmod +x /usr/local/bin/cloud_sql_proxy

RUN pip3 install poetry

ENV LC_ALL C.UTF-8
ENV LANG C.UTF-8

# -- Install Application into container:
WORKDIR /app

COPY pyproject.toml pyproject.toml
COPY poetry.lock poetry.lock

RUN poetry config virtualenvs.create false && poetry install

COPY . /app

ARG GIT_VERSION
ENV GIT_VERSION $GIT_VERSION
ENTRYPOINT ["/app/etc/entry"]
CMD ["web-prod"]
```

When running docker-compose up i got this error: `django.db.utils.OperationalError: (1045, "Access denied for user 'intranet'@'172.19.0.3' (using password: NO)")`
Tried searching for this but nothing helped. I will also provide readme from my project:

##### you need to install:

- poetry
- mysql@5.7
- python3.7
- node v16

### Backend

Make sure you have the `intranet` database created in MySQL.
If not, you might want to use the following commands:

```
mysql -u root -p
CREATE USER 'intranet'@'localhost';
CREATE DATABASE intranet;
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON intranet.* TO 'intranet'@'localhost';
FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
exit;
```

Then:

1. `poetry install`
2. `poetry shell`
3. `export DATABASE_URL='mysql2://intranet@localhost:3306/intranet'`
4. `export SECRET_KEY='x'`
5. `./manage.py migrate`
6. `./manage.py update_perms`
7. `./manage.py createcachetable`
8. `./manage.py runserver`

BTW. I write docker-compose file myself that's why I think it my be a problem. I will really appreciate answers that tell me fix step by step, thank you

Answer (score 0):

UPDATE:
if u have this problem double check if your projects is using postgres instead of mysql on development

correct docker-compose file:

```
version: "2.1"
services:
  database:
    image: postgres:11
    container_name: ni-db
    restart: on-failure
    ports:
      - 5436:5432 # to avoid conflicts with other projects
    volumes:
      - ./.testdb:/var/lib/postgresql/data
    environment:
      POSTGRES_HOST_AUTH_METHOD: trust
      POSTGRES_DB: backend
    healthcheck:
      test: ["CMD", "pg_isready", "-U", "postgres"]
      interval: 10s
      timeout: 5s
      retries: 5

  migrations:
    build: .
    image: ni-backend
    container_name: ni-migrations
    restart: on-failure
    env_file:
      - ./.env
    environment:
      DATABASE_URL: postgresql://postgres@database/backend
      SECRET_KEY: x
    volumes:
      - ./:/app
    command: ["python", "manage.py", "migrate"]
    depends_on:
      database:
        condition: service_healthy

  backend_api:
    image: ni-backend
    container_name: ni-api
    restart: on-failure
    env_file:
      - ./.env
    environment:
      DATABASE_URL: postgresql://postgres@database/backend
      SECRET_KEY: x
    ports:
      - 8000:80
    volumes:
      - ./:/app
    command: ["python", "manage.py", "runserver", "0.0.0.0:80"]
    depends_on:
      migrations:
        condition: service_started
```